# Execute the hover callback function even if the first one is interrupted 

Tags: jquery, hover, hoverintent

To see the problem try to mouse over the menu and while the animation is still going to move the pointer out of it. For expected behavior leave the mouse in the menu until the animation is finished and then move the pointer out of it. 
I guess that i am missing to add ,,stop()" somewhere, but atm i can't see what I am doing wrong.

Here is the jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DpXXT/4/

And the actual menu on website in progress: http://johnnystakes.co.uk/oko/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure about ".transition" method you use in your code. But original jQuery ".animate()" method has a property "queue" and I think having it "false" stops running animation in favor of the newly triggered one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for my problem using timeout function. Not perfect, but it works... [jfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DpXXT/24)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and got it working a little better, it's still not perfect but i imagine it would help, i need to leave so this is better than nothing: http://jsfiddle.net/2eZsk/

Comment: Friend, thats not working correct. Try to leave the navigation area before the finish of the animation. Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/DpXXT/24/ , that is almost what i want to achieve, but i would like to stop the animation being executed to the end if you move your mouse out, if that is possible somehow?

Comment: you could use `$('#nav').on('mouseleave',function(){ //reset everything });`

Comment: Isn't hover equal to mouseenter + mouseleave?

Comment: yes but not necessarily, as you can see in here hover will trigger both of them, so i think the best way to approach this without changing more code would be to just force it back to default with `onmouseleave`